# How to specify a Boundary on my multipart/form-data request?

Tags: angularjs, http, multipartform-data, boundary

I'm trying to send some form-data files to my backend, and I have this issue which consists on the browser (or server, or whatever) keeps ignoring the boundary I have defined and changing on my request payload to some WebKitFormBoundary random generated boundary.

This is what I have defined on my request

```
.factory('FilesPaymentsImportationsUploadResource', function ($resource, PAYMENTS_API_URL) {
            return $resource(PAYMENTS_API_URL + '/v1/payment-files/upload/', { id: "@id" }, {
                save: {
                    method: "POST",
                    transformRequest: angular.identity,
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----border----',
                        'Accept': 'application/json'
                    }
                }
            });
        })
```

So, I expected that on my RequestPayload to look likes this:

> ----border----
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file_content"; filename="text.txt" Content-Type: text/plain
>
> ----border----
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="from_user"
>
> test1
>
> ----border----
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="to_user"
>
> test2
>
> ----border----

But instead I have

> ------WebKitFormBoundary7GOXLp9hM5A0TLgS Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file_content"; filename="text.txt" Content-Type:
> text/plain
>
> ------WebKitFormBoundary7GOXLp9hM5A0TLgS Content-Disposition: form-data; name="from_user"
>
> Bonina2
> ------WebKitFormBoundary7GOXLp9hM5A0TLgS Content-Disposition: form-data; name="to_user"
>
> Caioteste
> ------WebKitFormBoundary7GOXLp9hM5A0TLgS--

My Request Header seems to be right, as I expected, I send:

> Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----border----

But it causes me trouble since I define one value to boundary and the form-data has another, which causes the server to lost the form and says I'm sending an empty form-data.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seemed to be related with angular $resorce. When I changed to $http, the problem has disappeared.